# How to identify various string patterns in rows in Pandas dataframes when there are various values in between raws

Tags: python, pandas, string, design-patterns, named-entity-recognition

```
Entity  Identified
0   Ref-Name    T.M.Chanika
1   Location    Kandy
2   Email   chanikalakmini23@gmail.com
3   Degree  Certificate Level of REVIT
4   Degree  Certificate Level of ADVANCED COMPUTER
5   Skill   Auto Cad
6   Degree  Certificate Level of ADVANCED COMPUTER
7   Skill   3D MODELLING using
8   Skill   Auto Cad
9   Institute   University of Moratuwa of Mechanical Engineering
10  Degree  NVQ Level 05 -Technical
```

Here I want to find some patterns that outputs in a NER model. For example (Name, Location, Email) pattern & (Degree, Institute) pattern. How we can do this using Pandas. If all the pattern are in order we can use some thing like this
pattern = ['Ref-Name','Location','Email']

```
pat_i = [df[i-len(pattern):i] # Get the index 
 for i in range(len(pattern), len(df)) # for each 3 consequent elements 
 if all(df['Entity'][i-len(pattern):i] == pattern)] # if the pattern matched
pat_i

[     Entity                 Identified
 0  Ref-Name                T.M.Chanika 
 1  Location                      Kandy
 2     Email  chanikalakmini23@gmail.com]
```

How we can identify patterns if there are values in between like in Degree & Institute

Answer (score 0):

I maybe misunderstood your contexte, but it does not look like NER at all, basically key groups where you want the n first rows, since your example data is structured?

If it is right, python is not even needed, most databases can do it easily.

Comment: This is the result I get from the NER model that was trained with SpaCy. Pattern changes depending on the Resume we are testing. So pattern always does not is not in the same format. So what I need to do is finding different patterns including exceptions that can happen

Comment: Alright, I indeed misunderstood your context. 
You can look at fptree & apriori algorithm on your Entity column.
That will extract token patterns, with every possible length, with associated count and association rules.
Could that fit your need?